# Unable to connect with PostgreSQL with command line psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

I have been trying to connect with the newly created PostgreSQL database. But in the command line, it is showing

```
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed, FATAL: password authentication failed for user <user>
```

I am entering the right password but still having the issue

Comment: The error message is specific the password failed. So either you are using the wrong password or you are connecting to a different Postgres  instance then you think you are.

Comment: Look in the db log file for a (possibly) more detailed error message.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this issue:

In my case entered username was incorrect.

I checked `installation_summary.txt` file to know the username.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).